# startActivityForResult() dont call to onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)?

Tags: android

i learn android and i am a beginner,
i tried to get a pic and turn it to my imageview, 
but in debug mode i see that app execute the line :
        startActivityForResult(i,camdata);
bring me to the cam window and after i get pic it ask me to save the pic and i save it.
after that noting happen - i mean i dont reach the line  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data).
why?
the code:

```
package com.thenewboston.elyakim;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Cam extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ImageButton ib;
    Button b;
    ImageView iv;
    Intent i;
    final static int camdata = 0;
    Bitmap bmp ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo);
        initialize();
        InputStream is1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is1);

    }
    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ib = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        ib.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            try {
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case R.id.imageButton1:
            i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i,camdata);
            break;

        }

        }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            bmp  = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(requestCode==RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp  = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

must be

```
if(requestCode==camdata){
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        iv.setImageUri(Uri.parse(data.getDataString()));
    }
}
```

the above displays the selected  image in the imageview