# Call startActivityForResult from Fragment doesn't call onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a `DialogActivity` which is called from a `Fragment` for show a custom `Dialog` with two image buttons.

In `DialogActivity.onCreate`

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_pause); 
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.show();
```

In `DialogActivity.onClick`

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "onClick CONTINUE");

            Intent resultData = new Intent();
            resultData.putExtra("TEST", "return data");
            setResult(666, resultData);
            dialog.cancel();
        }
```

In Fragment that calls `startActivityForResult`:

```
Intent dialogActivityIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DialogActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(dialogActivityIntent, 999);
```

In `Activity` and `Fragment` that calls `startActivityForResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

When I click the button I only get the dialog cancel and shows the background activity (fragment).

There isn't any call to `onActivityResult`, `onResume`, ... in the `Fragment` or  the `Activity` contains the `Fragment`.

### Things I tried:

To implement `onActivityResult` in both, `Fragment` and `Activity` that contains my `Fragment`.

### Things to know:

I set the attribute `noHistory=true` in every `Activity` I have.

If I do `finish()` in `onClick` the `Activity/Fragment` that calls `DialogActivity` is closed too, and the application return to the before `Activity`.

**This may be the problem, I DON'T call `finish()` ... but if I call `finish()`, it exits to another `Activity`, not the `Activity` that calls `startActivityForResult`.**

### Links I checked:

[startActivityForResult() dont call to onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867495/startactivityforresult-dont-call-to-onactivityresultint-requestcode-int-resu)

[Cannot get to trigger onActivityResult() android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017281/cannot-get-to-trigger-onactivityresult-android)

[startActivityForResult doesn't seem to call onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645489/startactivityforresult-doesnt-seem-to-call-onactivityresult)

[onActivityResult never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302085/onactivityresult-never-called)

[Android onActivityResult NEVER called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812120/android-onactivityresult-never-called)

[onActivityResult() not called when Activity started from Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839434/onactivityresult-not-called-when-activity-started-from-fragment)

---

I hope everything is clearly explained ^^.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `getActivity().startActivityForResult(dialogActivityIntent, 999);` and catch the result in the `Activity` which hosts the `Fragment`

Comment: I have tried that, the code was that just a minute before post my ask. Thanks :(

Comment: Does the `Activity` you want the result from does  have `android:launchMode` specified to `singleInstance` or `singleTask` in the manifest file?

Comment: See this link may help you:https://www.androidtutorialonline.com/onactivityresult-in-fragment/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Activities that have the attribute `noHistory=true` will never have their `onActivityResult()` called when launching a new `Activity` via `startActivityForResult()`. As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) mentions, when the `noHistory` attribute is set to `true`, then `finish()` is called on the `Activity` when the user navigates away from the `Activity`.

So, when `startActivityForResult()` is called, the `Activity` is navigated away from, causing its `finish()` to be called and making it never receive a call to `onActivityResult()`. If you remove the `noHistory=true` attribute from the `Activity` that's calling `startActivityForResult()`, then call `finish()` in your `DialogActivity`'s `onClick()`, then you should still see the `Activity` that launched it, as well as receive a call to `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment... I solved this problem some days later doing what you say.
Thanks!

Comment: great @ashu.. it solved my two problems first my activity was getting closed as soon as display turned off secondly the same problem mentioned in the question..thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Close all the activities after you are done with the result.
For example, in your overridden onActivityResult you can add finishActivity (activity 1..N). Don't forget to place each under try catch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30669944)